# Error while installing tensorflow: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) to install tensorflow. However, when I execute the command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions): No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

My machine is 32 bits. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: could you please type the following 3 commands? 'which python`, `whereis python` and lastly `pip freeze` and share the results for each command?

Comment: I am getting error message "which is not recognize as internal or external command"

Comment: Are you on a linux based machine or on windows?

Comment: windows! I think the problem is with the 32 bits or 64 its python

Comment: My apologies! I assumed you were on a unix based system!

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I installed python 3.6.5 32 bits! Just a quick check, can I install python 64 bits on machine with 32 bits? I am having troubles to install the 64 bits one

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found an [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-TensorFlow-in-a-32-bit-Windows-computer-for-the-Python-3-6-version). Tensorflow does not support 32bits machine. I guess I will have to find another workarounds.

Comment: Glad that you were able to resolve the problem! Sorry that it doesn't work on 32 bit machines!